# How to save fetch response as input value

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to capture the client-side IP address and automatically store it as the value inside of an input field. Here's my code so far:

```
var Ip;
fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => Ip = data.ip)
  .then(() => console.log(Ip))
  .then(() => document.getElementById('awf_field-106493013').value = Ip);
```

This is returning the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

`.value` is the bit of code it doesn't like, which seems to mean `awf_field-106493013` is null, but I know for a fact by the time this function has been called the input has populated, and I'm positive this is the correct input id.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Here's what the input looks like:

```
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-106493013">ipaddress:</label>
<div class="af-textWrap"><input type="text" id="awf_field-106493013" class="text" name="custom ipaddress" value=""  onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="503" /></div>
```

This is all called before the javascript code so it should be there.

**Edit 2** Here's all the javascript I currently have on my page, I just made it so when the document is ready, then the `fetch` is made:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getUrlParam(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
  var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
      results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var tid = getUrlParam("adid");
var date = Date(Date.now());

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  setIp();

  jQuery('#awf_field-106493014').val(date.toString()); //Time
  if (tid != null) {
    jQuery('#awf_field-106493015').val(tid.toString()); //Tid
  } else {
    jQuery('#awf_field-106493015').val("nulltid"); //Tid
  }
});

function setIp(){
  var Ip;
  fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => Ip = data.ip)
    .then(() => console.log(Ip))
    .then(() => document.getElementById('awf_field-106493013').value = Ip);
}
</script>
```

Returns the same

Comment: You can check if that element is loaded or not and then call your fetch request.

Comment: Haven't you tested yet whether `getElementById` returns a non-null value?

Comment: I suspect the argument chaining is incomplete: `.then(res => res.json()).then(data => data.ip).then(ip => { console.log(ip); return ip; }).then(ip => document.getElementById('awf_field-106493013').value = ip);` should fix it.

Comment: Seems to me like there is no element with `id="awf_field-106493013"`. *"Return value: An [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object describing the DOM element object matching the specified ID, or `null` if no matching element was found in the document."* - [`Document.getElementById()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Works fine, provided the element ID is correct. https://jsfiddle.net/4tphdur9/

Comment: @collapsar nope, that wasn't it

Comment: @3limin4t0r check edit

Comment: @Ethan Could you add a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that demonstrates the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Still works fine on the fiddle I've provided. https://jsfiddle.net/4tphdur9/1/

Comment: @3limin4t0r check edit 2, I don't know how to use snippets here, and I'm not sure how to create an MRE off a wordpress site, which is what this code is running on.

Comment: @3limin4t0r @emsoff something else is definitely wrong here. When I try   `jQuery.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json",
                function(data){
                   alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);
                        jQuery('#awf_field-106493013').val(data.ip); //Ip
              });` the alert works, but the input isn't filled.. I'm clueless as to why, not like it is a number only input field...

Comment: @emsoff FYI, read last comment, I also changed that jQuery around to select ANY other field on the form, none of them work from within that get Function, the other fields are filled just fine, except for whichever I call inside there

Comment: jQuery always returns an jQuery collection, if the id `awf_field-106493013` isn't there the collection is empty and the value `data.ip` will be set on nothing. The number at the end of `awf_field-106493013` makes me believe that the id is randomly generated. Have you checked if the numbers stay the same on a refresh?

Comment: @Ethan bizarre. It has worked without fail the 20+ times I've tried.

Comment: please check your devtools console, it may be there some error, did you try my answer? if didnt work il delete it

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes, I've checked, those are static id's. `jQuery('#awf_field-106493014').val(date.toString());` inside of the Document ready function works to replace it's designated fields, but as soon as you put an identical query with the updated ID inside of a `.get` function it fails. No errors in console.

Comment: Could it be that the `awf_field-106493013` element is lazily loaded and `document` triggers its ready function before the element in question is loaded in? For example YouTube comments are loaded through AJAX and only available after you scroll down.

Comment: @3limin4t0r that wouldn't make sense because the other inputs that are a part of the same element are loaded and filled by the other jQuery calls with no issues

Comment: The error message says that the element (`awf_field-106493013`)could not be retrieved. Whatever the reason, try another selector (see my updated answer for a suggestion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by modifying `https://api.ipify.org/?format=json`, which returns abck some sort of weird json object to `https://api.ipify.org/` which, as per their documentation, returns back a standard `text` reply.

Answer (score 1):

The code from the question works with me - run the snippet. The last JS line uses an alternative selector for the target input field, but the original line (commented out here) works just as fine.

```js
function getUrlParam(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
  var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
      results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var tid = getUrlParam("adid");
var date = Date(Date.now());

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  setIp();

  jQuery('#awf_field-106493014').val(date.toString()); //Time
  if (tid != null) {
    jQuery('#awf_field-106493015').val(tid.toString()); //Tid
  } else {
    jQuery('#awf_field-106493015').val("nulltid"); //Tid
  }
});

function setIp(){
  var Ip;
  fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => Ip = data.ip)
    .then(() => console.log(Ip))
    .then(() => document.querySelector('*[name="custom ipaddress"]').value = Ip);
// was:        .then(() => document.getElementById('awf_field-106493013').value = Ip);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-106493013">ipaddress:</label>
<div class="af-textWrap"><input type="text" id="awf_field-106493013" class="text" name="custom ipaddress" value=""  onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="503" /></div>
```

***Remark***

This is not a genuine answer. It serves to sort out the OP's issue and will be modified or deleted thereafter

Comment: unfortunately I am not able to modify the name of the input field as it was generated by Aweber

Comment: You don't have to. In your original code you referenced the input element by its id. The `name` attribute should be unique as well - check that. You have the power of CSS selectors at your disposition to uniquely identify an element in the DOM. If you use positional information only, you do not even have to resort to attributes at all ( This is not an advisable solution, though ).

Answer (score 0):

the url you used to fetch ip didn't work on my machine, changed API provider and now it works fine.

```
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-106493013">ipaddress:</label>
<div class="af-textWrap">
    <input type="text" id="awf_field-106493013" class="text" name="custom ipaddress" value=""  onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="503" />
</div>
<script>
var Ip;
fetch('http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=status,query')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => Ip = data.query)
  .then(() => console.log(Ip))
  .then(() => document.getElementById('awf_field-106493013').value = Ip);
</script>
```